# Does SemaphoreSlim act as a gatekeeper or as a batchkeeper?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, semaphore

Does SemaphoreSlim act as a gatekeeper or as a batchkeeper?

For example: assuming I have `semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(50, 50);`, and suppose I have to perform 1000 tasks.

Does the `semaphore.Wait();` or `semaphore.WaitAsync();` ensure that 50 tasks are processed as a batch - for example - perform 50 tasks, and when all 50 are complete then do the next 50, and so on..

Or does it act like gatekeeper - for example - perform 50 tasks, then as soon as even 1 task is complete, perform the 51st task, and so on?

Comment: It's a gatekeeper.